# React Redux state not updating when using non mutable methods

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Greetings I am having problems updating the state of my app.

**Everything works fine** if I use methods that break the mutability principle of React.
Here is my state:

```
const state= {
    cart: {
        items: [
            {
                productId: "A1",
                quantity: "1",
                unitPrice: "9"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

action.payload is:

```
{productId: "A2", quantity: "1", unitPrice: "11"}
```

it works with this:

```
case ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART: 
  state.cart.items.push(action.payload);
  return state;
```

But, I want to use a better approach. Like this one:

```
case ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART: 
  return {
  ...state, 
  items: [action.payload, ...state.cart.items]   
  };
```

But it does not update my state. **store.getState()** outputs the initial state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `cart` key.

This should work:

```
case ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART: 

  return {
    ...state, 
    cart: {                  // add cart key
      ...state.cart,
      items: [
        ...state.cart.items,
        action.payload       // new items will be the last
      ]
    }
  };
```